# How to get custom parameters in PushNotificationIOS in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, react-native-ios

I have the following response from `PushNotification` in `iOS` for `react-native`

```
{
  "aps": {
    "alert": "Next live session will start on 15-10-2018 13:00:00 for course NEET\/AIIMS",
    "sound": "default",
    "badge": 1,
    "relData": {
      "video_url": "",
      "start_time": "15-10-2018 13:00:00"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I get `start_time` from `relData` using `PushNotificatonIOS` ?

Currently I am only able to get the alert message using this code:

```
PushNotificationIOS.addEventListener('notification', function(notification) {
    console.log('You have received a new notification! ', notification);
    Alert.alert(notification.getMessage())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `APNS notification` content to the following format.

```
{
    "aps": {
      "alert": {
          "title": "Some Title",
          "body": "Next live session will start on 15-10-2018 13:00:00 for course NEET\/AIIMS"
      },
      "sound": "default",
      "badge": 1,
      "mutable-content": 1,
      "content-available": 1
    },
    "relData": {
        "video_url": "",
        "start_time": "15-10-2018 13:00:00"
    }
}
```

From `Apple` docs. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html

> To support a background update notification, make sure that the
>   payload’s aps dictionary includes the **content-available** key with a
>   value of **1**. If there are user-visible updates that go along with the
>   background update, you can set the alert, sound, or badge keys in the
>   aps dictionary, as appropriate.

At the top of your AppDelegate.m:

```
#import <React/RCTPushNotificationManager.h>
```

And then in your AppDelegate implementation add the following:

```
// Required for the notification event. You must call the completion handler after handling the remote notification.
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
                                                        fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
 {
   [RCTPushNotificationManager didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
 }
```

You will get the `relData` along with rest of the payload in `userInfo` in above method.

For more please visit https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios

Comment: How would i be able to get "relData" if i do that ? using react-native code

Comment: i have already added my code in the app delegate and even able to get alert message in the react native code. My question is how can i access "relData" ? Is it possible by using notification.relData.start_time in the PushNotificationIOS.addEventListener('notification', function(notification) ?

Comment: please help me... @Sateesh

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Check in **console.log('You have received a new notification! ', notification);** after the payload is updated with content what I've shared.